# Play Audio on Java EE web application on client side (browser)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, audio, client

We are trying to play audio on the client machine. It is a web application based on Java EE, wherein due to some event happening at server side, the client should ring a bell or something of that sort.

I am not aware of any such thing. Alternative is to use

> Html5

, but then it's become browser dependent that the browser should be Html5 compatible. I cannot enforce this requirement onto the client.

I went through

> Red5

but found it not very useful..

Please advise

Comment: I guess you can clearly notify the server events on the client/browser, the only issue that is present now is playing audio.

Comment: Yes..I am already notifying my client of changes done on server. That is not a problem. The only issue is playing audio on client when something happens on server.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to the problem:

- playing sound in a browser
- the browser being notified of events on the server

For playing sounds, and to support a wide range of browsers, you have a number of options.  HTML5 `<audio>` tag and Plugins (Flash, Java applet).  You could also use a Javascript library such as Yahoo Media Player to make this easier.  A starter is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp).

The second problem is how to notify clients when an event on the server occurs.  This could be done with AJAX calls polling the server.  Since you are using Java EE, this could be made a bit more efficient using [Asynchronous Servlets](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1437).  You could also go down the [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) path with this as well, though there can be issues through proxy servers with this.

Comment: <audio> tag is available only in HTML5 . I have already mentioned I cannot enforce this requirement on the client. I cannot use a javascript library which establishes a connection on http as my application is on Intranet. NO communication with outside world. I am already polling server for the information so that case is not a problem. My only problem is to play a sound on the client as soon as   a value is added in arraylist in the server side.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons Flash or Java applet will still work on an Intranet if you put the flash SWF file or applet JAR file on your server.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to embed the flash SWF or applet JAR file in the application. A demo code playing the sound can be of great help...